# Redirecting Based on user-agent

Tags: javascript, asp.net, redirect, user-agent

I would like to redirect all the unwanted request pages to a url

i get example.com/garbage-value request on my server in bulk like 2000+ every day
The request have no user agent in it , it shows up in the analytics

so i want to stop them,i thought that the possible way is to redirect them.

the site is made in asp

can we implement in asp or javascript or is there any other way to do so.

i was thinking of something like this but it did not worked

```
    //For an iPhone/iPod site:

if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') != -1)) {
                document.location = "http://URL.com/iphone/";
        } 
----------------------------------------

//For an iPad site:

if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1)) {
                document.location = "http://URL.com/ipad/";
        }
```

Comment: If they're coming to a garbage value URL, they're probably bots evit anyway, and will probably be lying about their User Agent. So there's not much point redirecting them based on their UA string. In fact, they're already getting a 404 error, so why bother redirecting them any further?

Comment: That increases the bounce rate and can be used for negative seo techniques